# problema con acentos en un campo de una tabla en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, datos

Tengo el siguiente problema referente a acentos en mysql, poseo un campo llamado "name" de una tabla llamada "regions", dicho campo contiene datos de diferentes regiones, pero no toma los datos que llevan acentos, como por ejemplo: región, para contextualizar más lo acabo de detallar, dejo la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desafortunadamente no he podido solucionarlo, incluso he cambiado el cotejamiento y sigue apareciendo el problema:

(Este el cotejamiento actual que posee)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Casi siempre el problema con los acentos y demás caracteres especiales se debe al cotejamiento. Yo personalmente uso `utf8mb4_bin` y nunca he tenido problemas con eso. Puedes intentar probar con ese.